# Cascading op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

I am trying to figure out the gain of the following circuit:
[image]

What I have done so far is looking at each amplifier independently:
$$
U_3=-R_9/R_8=-4
$$
$$
U_4=R_{10}+R_{11}/R_{10}=3
$$
$$
V_o=-R_9/R_8 \times (R_{10}+R_{11}/R_{10})=-12
$$
And have gotten -12 as the final answer. However, the questions hints at "cascading the transfer functions". Does my method look correct? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm baffled as to why you think U3 inverts but U4 doesn't.

Comment: This looks like two inverting amps to me.  So your -12 gain is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Gain = -4 * -2 , Offset = 2V * (2+1)

Comment: @Finbarr I have been staring at the circuit and the only conclusion I can come to is I am neglecting the V1, so does that mean I will have to multiply it by -1 and V1 to get my corresponding gain? The V1 is throwing me off...

Comment: Nope...... . . .

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Ah ok, because the input of the inverting and noninverting inputs must equal then I must multiply by the 2V times the gain for my transfer function, resulting in a gain of 6. However, I am still achieving a negative gain of -24...

Comment: Use KCL at U4's inverting input.

Comment: Hint: The output of U3 can be considered to be *a very low impedance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a tricky case. You actually have two inputs: \$V_{in} \$ and \$V_p \$, the voltage source connected to + in your second op-amp. Both these sources affect \$V_o \$ so to find the effect from each source you need to use superposition.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP2KHe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Case 1: \$V_p =0\$**

The node equations become
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{V_1-V_{in}}{R_8}+\frac{V_1-U_3}{R9}=0\\\\
\frac{V_2-U_3}{R_{10}}+\frac{V_2-V_o}{R_{11}}=0
\end{cases} $$
With \$V_1=0 \$ and \$V_p=0 \$ and the principle of a **virtual short** you get \$V_o=V_{in} \frac{R_{11}R_9}{R_{10}R_8} \$.

**Case 2: \$V_{in}=0 \$**

The node equations are the same
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{V_1-V_{in}}{R_8}+\frac{V_1-U_3}{R9}=0\\\\
\frac{V_2-U_3}{R_{10}}+\frac{V_2-V_o}{R_{11}}=0
\end{cases} $$
With \$V_1=0 \$, \$V_2=V_p\$ and \$V_{in}=0 \$ and the principle of a **virtual short** you get \$V_o = V_p \frac{R_{10}+R_{11}}{R_{10}} \$

**The total response:**
$$V_{o,total}=V_{in} \frac{R_{11}R_9}{R_{10}R_8}+V_p \frac{R_{10}+R_{11}}{R_{10}} $$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Your a lifesaver

Comment: For me, the gain is only the factor multiplying \$V_{in}\$, in this case \$\frac{R_{11}R_9}{R_{10}R_8}\$ everything else is just an offset.
@thediyer the key technique for the analysis (already mentioned by Carl) is "Superposition" worth reading about it.

Answer (score 1):

The "aggregate", "net", "combined", or "compound" transfer function of cascaded amplifier stages is sometimes quoted to be the simple product of the transfer functions of the individual stages, but this is only true if every stage implements a simple direct proportionality, like \$ V_{OUT} = -3 \times V_{IN} \$.

Your second stage introduces an offset \$ V_1 \$ which invalidates that approach.

Here you must use [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) to obtain the ouput \$ V_{OUT} \$ as a function of some input \$ V_{IN} \$:

$$ V_{OUT} = h( V_{IN} ) $$

To illustrate, I'll redraw your circuit with some extra annotations, to visually segregate the stages, and give us some variables to work with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU9SbZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer functions of stages 1 and 2 are \$ f \$ and \$ g \$ respectively, so that:

$$ V_F = f(V_{IN}) $$
$$ V_{OUT} = g(V_F) $$

The two functions must be composed to obtain the overall transfer function:

$$ V_{OUT} = h(V_{IN}) = g(V_F) = g(f(V_{IN})) $$

Sometimes you see this written as \$ h = g \circ f \$, which I read as "g of f" or "g about f".

The first stage transfer function \$f\$ is very simple. I assume you are familiar with the opamp configured as a simple inverting amplifier:

$$ f(V_{IN}) = -\frac{R_9}{R_8} \times V_{IN} $$

The second stage function \$g\$ is less trivial, because of the offset \$V_A\$ due to \$V_1\$. To simplify the algebra we can employ what we know about opamps with negative feedback, which is that the opamp adjusts its output to equalise the potentials at its inverting and non-inverting inputs:

$$ V_A = V_B = 2V $$

Then construct the usual KCL and Ohm's law equations, and solve for \$ V_{OUT} \$ as a function of \$ V_F \$ and \$ V_A \$:

$$ I = \frac{V_{OUT} - V_B}{R_{11}} $$

$$ I = \frac{V_B - V_F}{R_{10}} $$

$$ V_{OUT} = \frac{R_{11}}{R_{10}}(V_A - V_F) + V_A $$

Intuitively, you can interpret this to mean that the stage amplifies the *difference between \$V_A\$ and the input*, with the usual gain of \$ -\frac{R_{11}}{R_{10}} \$, but also offsets the output by an additional amount  \$V_A\$.

The penultimate step is to compose the functions:

$$ \begin{aligned}
h(V_{IN}) &= g(f(V_{IN})) \newline
\newline
&= \frac{R_{11}}{R_{10}}(V_A - f(V_{IN})) + V_A \newline
\newline
&= \frac{R_{11}}{R_{10}}(V_A + \frac{R_9}{R_8}V_{IN}) + V_A
\end{aligned} $$

Lastly we plug in the resistances to get:

$$ \begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= 2(2V + 4\cdot V_{IN}) + 2V
\newline
\newline
&= 6V + 8 \cdot V_{IN}
\end{aligned} $$